# _.template не видит IE11

Tags: javascript, babel

Есть код:

```js
"use strict";
var commonTemplates = {
  templateCartItem: _.template(
    '\n        <tr data-item-id="<%- id %>">\n            <td class="cursor-pointer cell-check" style="padding-left: 6px">\n                <input type="checkbox" class="d-none" <%- selected ? "checked" : "" %>/>\n                <i class="fas fa-check-square text-success"></i>\n                <i class="fas fa-square text-gray"></i>\n            </td>\n            <td class="cursor-pointer cell-del">\n                <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>\n            </td>\n            <td><%- index + 1 %></td>\n            <td><%- id %></td>\n            <td>\n                <a href="#exampleModalCenter" data-toggle="modal">\n                    <div class="bg-img img-40 mx-auto" style="background-image: url(\'<%- front_image %>\')"></div>\n                </a>\n            </td>\n            <td class="text-left">\n                <a href="#exampleModalCenter" data-toggle="modal" class="d-flex align-items-center">\n                    <div><%- name %></div>\n                </a>\n            </td>\n            <td>\n                <div class="btn-group counter">\n                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white counter-minus">-</button>\n                    <input class="btn btn-white border-top border-bottom px-1" type="number" value=<%- count %>>\n                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white counter-plus">+</button>\n                </div>\n            </td>\n            <td><%- formatter.format(price.finaly ? price.finaly : price.standart) %> \u0440</td>\n            <td><%- formatter.format(count * (price.finaly ? price.finaly : price.standart)) %> \u0440</td>\n        </tr>'
  ),
  templatePath: _.template(
    '\n        <% if (home) { %>\n            <li class="breadcrumb-item">\n                <a href="<%- home %>">\u0413\u043B\u0430\u0432\u043D\u0430\u044F</a>\n            </li>\n        <% } %>\n        <% path.map((item) => { %>\n            <li class="breadcrumb-item">\n                <a href="categories.html?category=<%- item.id %>"><%- item.name %></a>\n            </li>\n        <% }) %>\n\n        <li class="breadcrumb-item">\n            <a href="<%- parent.folder ? "categories" : "price"%>.html?category=<%- parent.id %>"><%- parent.name %> <span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill"><%- parent.count %></span></a>\n        </li>'
  ),
  templateCategory: _.template(
    '\n        <div class="card <%- bg %> mb-3 mr-25 p-1 border-0">\n            <a class="h-100 d-flex flex-column <%- text %>" href="<%- folder ? "categories" : "price" %>.html?category=<%- id %><%- sale ? "&sale" : "" %>">\n                <% if (image) { %>\n                    <div class="card-body p-0 bg-img mx-auto" style="background-image: url(\'<%- image %>\')">\n                        <% if (folder) { %>\n                            <div class="d-inline px-2 pt-3 pb-2">\n                                <i class="fas fa-folder-open mt-2" style="font-size: 24px"></i>\n                            </div>\n                        <% } %>\n                    </div>\n                <% } else { %>\n                    <div class="text-center bg-img my-auto d-flex align-items-center">\n                        <i class="fas fa-question fa-7x mx-auto"></i>\n                    </div>\n                <% } %>\n\n                <% if (folder) { %>\n                    <div class="d-inline px-2 pb-2 position-absolute">\n                        <i class="fas fa-folder-open mt-2 text-warning" style="font-size: 24px"></i>\n                    </div>\n                <% } %>\n\n                <div class="text-left font-weight-500 px-2 my-auto">\n                    <%- name %> <%- count > 0 ? "(" + count + ")" : "" %>\n                </div>\n            </a>\n        </div>'
  ),
  colors: [{ bg: "bg-dark", text: "text-light" }],
  templatePageLinkLeft:
    '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link bg-transparent no-focus-shadow" href="#">&laquo;</a></li>',
  templatePageLinkRight:
    '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link bg-transparent no-focus-shadow" href="#">&raquo;</a></li>',
  templatePageLinkDots:
    '<li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link bg-transparent" tabindex="-1">...</span></li>',
  templatePageLink: _.template(
    '<li class="page-item <%- active ? "active" : "" %>">\n            <a class="page-link bg-transparent no-focus-shadow" href="#"><%- page %></a>\n        </li>'
  ),
  templateEmptyTreeItem: _.template(
    '\n        <a href="price.html?category=<%- id %>">\n            <%- name %><%= count > 0 ? \'<span class="ml-2 badge badge-warning">\' + count + \'</span>\' : "" %>\n        </a>'
  ),
  templateManagerBody: _.template(
    '\n        <div class="d-flex">\n            <div class="mr-3">\n                <img class="img-180 rounded-circle" src="<%- photo %>">\n            </div>\n\n            <div>\n                <% if (phone) { %>\n                    <div class="input-group mb-3">\n                        <div class="input-group-prepend">\n                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>\n                        </div>\n                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control bg-dark text-light" value="<%- phone %>">\n                    </div>\n                <% } %>\n\n                <% if (email) { %>\n                    <div class="input-group mb-3">\n                        <div class="input-group-prepend">\n                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>\n                        </div>\n                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control disabled bg-dark text-light" value="<%- email %>">\n                    </div>\n                <% } %>\n\n                <% if (skype) { %>\n                    <div class="input-group mb-3">\n                        <div class="input-group-prepend">\n                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fab fa-skype"></i></span>\n                        </div>\n                        <input readonly type="text" class="form-control disabled bg-dark text-light" value="<%- skype %>">\n                    </div>\n                <% } %>\n\n                <p><%- info %></p>\n            </div>\n        </div>'
  )
};
(commonTemplates.templateTreeItem = _.template(
  '\n    <% if (items != 0) { %>\n        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#cat<%- id %>">\n            <i class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></i>\n            <i class="fa fa-minus mr-2"></i>\n        </a>\n    <% } %>\n\n    <a href="price.html?category=<%- id %>">\n        <%- name %> <%= count > 0 ? \'<span class="badge badge-warning">\' + count + \'</span>\' : "" %>\n    </a>\n\n    <div id="cat<%- id %>" class="collapse pl-2" data-parent="#cat<%- parent %>">\n        <% items.map((item) => { %>\n            <div>\n                <%= item.items == 0 ? templateEmptyTreeItem()(item) : templateTreeItem()({ ...item, parent: id }) %>\n            </div>\n        <% }) %>\n    </div>',
  {
    imports: {
      templateTreeItem: function() {
        return commonTemplates.templateTreeItem;
      },
      templateEmptyTreeItem: function() {
        return commonTemplates.templateEmptyTreeItem;
      }
    }
  }
)),
  (commonTemplates.templateTree = _.template(
    '\n    <div class="card text-white bg-dark">\n        <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center">\n            <% if (items != 0) { %>\n                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#cat<%- id %>">\n                    <i class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></i>\n                    <i class="fa fa-minus mr-2"></i>\n                </a>\n            <% } %>\n\n            <a href="price.html?category=<%- id %>">\n                <%- name %> <%= count > 0 ? \'<span class="badge badge-warning">\' + count + \'</span>\' : "" %>\n            </a>\n        </div>\n\n        <% if (items != 0) { %>\n            <div class="collapse card-body accordion p-3" id="cat<%- id %>">\n                <% items.map((item) => { %>\n                    <div>\n                        <%= item.items == 0 ? templateEmptyTreeItem()(item) : templateTreeItem()({ ...item, parent: id }) %>\n                    </div>\n                <% }) %>\n            </div>\n        <% } %>\n    </div>',
    {
      imports: {
        templateTreeItem: function() {
          return commonTemplates.templateTreeItem;
        },
        templateEmptyTreeItem: function() {
          return commonTemplates.templateEmptyTreeItem;
        }
      }
    }
  ));
```

Я с помощью babel.js переделал код, но IE11 выдает ошибку: "_" не определено
common-templates.js (2,1)

В чем может быть проблема?

Код не мой, просто поставили задачу решить эту проблему.

Comment: IE11 не видит _.template*

Comment: Проблема как минимум в том, что в приведенном коде нигде не определена переменная `_`. Соответственно, ругаться будет любой браузер, не только IE.